# Como puedo acceder al StartupPath de un complemento VSTO de Excel?

Tags: c#

Necesito leer un archivo de texto de la carpeta `bin.`

Utilizo el `Application.StartupPath` de **windows forms**,

pero este me trae otra ruta.

Comment: Como usas Application.StartupPath , y si lo inspeccionas que valor tiene?

Comment: ya lo solucione. Gracias.

Comment: como hago para dar a conocer de que manera lo solucione? modifico mi consulta, o me respondo a mi mismo para mostrar de que manera lo solucione?

Comment: Te respondes a ti mismo y aceptas la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías utilizar el método `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, este devolverá toda la ruta relativa de donde se encuentra el ejecutable (`.exe`) de tu aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

ya resolví el problema de la siguiente manera:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                string location = assembly.CodeBase;
                string fullPath = new Uri(location).LocalPath;
                string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
                StreamReader File = new StreamReader(directoryPath + "\\BD.hys");
```